# How to get rid of \ufeff in parsed html page

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

The code is

```
!wget -q -O 'boroughs.html' "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_London_boroughs"

with open('boroughs.html', encoding='utf-8-sig') as fp:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(fp,"lxml")


data = []
table = soup.find("table", { "class" : "wikitable sortable" })
table_body = table.find('tbody')
rows = table_body.find_all('tr')
for row in rows:
    cols = row.find_all('td')
    cols = [col.text.strip() for col in cols]
    data.append([col for col in cols]) # Get rid of empty values
data
```

I've added `encoding='utf-8-sig'` to open after some research. But in the output [I still see  the characters \ufeff:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LIbjG.png)

What puzzles me, I've even tried the hacky way with

```
df = df.replace(u'\ufeff', '')
```

after adding data to pandas dataframe

And the characters are still there.

Comment: Which version of python are you running?

Comment: Python 3.5.5 :: Anaconda, Inc.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [python utf-8-sig BOM in the middle of the file when appending to the end](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23154355/python-utf-8-sig-bom-in-the-middle-of-the-file-when-appending-to-the-end)

Comment: For utf-8-sig, I think you should be replacing ''\xef\xbb\xbf'. Or you can try decoding with str.decode('utf-8-sig')

Comment: @AlexandreJuma sorry, can you elaborate on this? Should I try str.decode on the column?

Comment: Have you tried `data.append([col.replace(u'\ufeff', '') for col in cols])` ?

Comment: I really feel I'm missing something obvious here... Added a line `df = df.append([col.replace(u'\ufeff', '') for col in columns])`. Then I do some data cleanup and as the last step I cast longitude column as float and get this error: `ValueError: ('Unable to parse string " 0.1557\ufeff " at position 0', 'occurred at index Longitude')` which i assume means, that \ufeff is still there?

Comment: Is there any reason for using pandas dataframes? I've just ran your code with a simple string replace and it works fine (i.e: removes \ufeff). I'll post an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've tried your code using **Python 3.6.1** with a simple `str.replace(u'\ufeff', '')` and it seems to work.

Code tested:

```
import os
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

os.system('wget -q -O "boroughs.html" "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_London_boroughs"')

with open('boroughs.html', encoding='utf-8-sig') as fp:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(fp,"lxml")

data = []
table = soup.find("table", { "class" : "wikitable sortable" })
table_body = table.find('tbody')
rows = table_body.find_all('tr')
for row in rows:
    cols = row.find_all('td')
    cols = [col.text.strip() for col in cols]
    data.append([col.replace(u'\ufeff', '') for col in cols])
print(data)
```

Output before replace:

> [[], ['Barking and Dagenham [note 1]', '', '', 'Barking and Dagenham
>   London Borough Council', 'Labour', 'Town Hall, 1 Town Square',
>   '13.93', '194,352', '51°33′39″N 0°09′21″E\ufeff / \ufeff51.5607°N
>   0.1557°E\ufeff / 51.5607; 0.1557\ufeff (Barking and Dagenham)', '25'], ... ]

Output after replace:

> [[], ['Barking and Dagenham [note 1]', '', '', 'Barking and Dagenham
>   London Borough Council', 'Labour', 'Town Hall, 1 Town Square',
>   '13.93', '194,352', '51°33′39″N 0°09′21″E / 51.5607°N0.1557°E /
>   51.5607; 0.1557 (Barking and Dagenham)', '25'], ... ]

Comment: Thanks! `data.append([col.replace(u'\ufeff', '') for col in cols])` or using `os.system` did the trick!! It did mess up column headings, but I'll have to fix this :D

Comment: Great. If no changes are required, you can accept the answer.

Answer (score 3):

Try the following:

```
with open('boroughs.html', encoding='utf-8-sig') as fp:
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `utf8` instead :

```py
with open('boroughs.html', encoding='utf8') as fp:
    doc = html.fromstring(fp.read())

    data = []
    rows = doc.xpath("//table/tbody/tr")
    for row in rows:
        cols = row.xpath("./td/text()")
        cols = [col.strip() for col in cols if col.strip()]
        data.append(cols)
```

Comment: I'm afraid, i'm getting the same results with `encoding=utf8'`